# If found, return value one tab over [java]

Tags: java, arrays

I've successfully created an item scanner for my game.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ItemScanner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.print("Enter item to find: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        find(sc.nextLine());

    }

    public static void find(String delim) {
        File dir = new File("accounts");
        if (dir.exists()) {
            String read;
            try {
                File files[] = dir.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    File loaded = files[i];
                    if (loaded.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loaded));
                        StringBuffer load = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            load.append(read + "\n");
                        }
                        String delimiter[] = new String(load).split(delim);
                        if(delimiter.length > 1) {
                                System.out.println("Found " + (I don't know how to read 1 tab over - 1) + " time(s) in " + loaded.getName() + "!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("error: dir wasn't found!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm on the last step of making my life easier when it comes to finding how many of this item the player has.

here's the scenario:

Search Item: 6570

Found [x] time(s) in Account.txt!

This is how the layout of the items are

account-item = 6570 1

It's read like this: 6570 is the item, then [tab] , 1 equals how much of the item that user has.

So if it says

account-item = 6570 24

The user has 24 of that item.

---

Problem:

I simply do not know how to return the value of the item from 1 tab over.

So if I search for 6570, and if it is found, how would i get the amount of the item being found? Here's my code to return the items

```
String delimiter[] = new String(load).split(delim);
                        if(delimiter.length > 1) {
                                System.out.println("Found " + (I don't know - 1) + " time(s) in " + loaded.getName() + "!");
                        }
```

Comment: Note that using the `new String()` constructor here is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the elements in array by addressing them using the array accessor.

if the String value of load in your example code is `6570<TAB>24`, your array elements will have the following values

```
delimiter[0] = '6570'
delimiter[1] = '24'
```

To get at the value '24', use delimiter[1]. For example

```
System.out.println("The value is " + delimiter[1]);
```

Will print

> The value is 24

Comment: What if the value was unknown and it just reads the value from the character?

Comment: When you split the string, the values in the array are set. Java arrays start at index 0 so the first value is at index 0, the second at index 1, etc. Accessing the elements does not rely on knowing the value in the element, just it's position.